# how to cluster two dimensional trajectories with x and y

Tags: r

I have some thousands of 2-dimensional trajectories in the x and y axes. The sample dataset is shown below. Each trajectory is represented in the form of x and y axes, and all the trajectories have different number of rows.

```
x1 = c(18.12,18.63,20.17,20.69,22.28,22.81,24.41,24.94,26.53,27.06,28.63,29.16,30.72,31.24,32.83,33.37,35.01,35.56,37.26,37.84,39.58,40.17,41.94,42.53,44.30,44.89,46.65,47.23,47.82,48.39)
y1 = c(16.19,16.68,18.14,18.61,20.03,20.50,21.88,22.32,23.64,24.07,25.34,25.76,26.98,27.38,28.57,28.96,30.13,30.52,31.67,32.05,33.19,33.56,34.66,35.02,36.07,36.41,37.38,37.69,37.99,38.29)
x2 = c(18.19,18.73,20.36,20.91,22.57,23.12,24.79,25.34,27.00,27.55,29.20,29.75,31.40,31.96,33.63,34.19,35.91,36.49,38.25,38.85,40.67,41.28,43.13,43.75,45.60,46.21,48.04,48.64)
y2= c(16.23,16.75,18.27,18.77,20.24,20.72,22.13,22.59,23.94,24.39,25.68,26.11,27.35,27.76,28.96,29.36,30.53,30.92,32.07,32.45,33.58,33.95,35.04,35.39,36.41,36.74,37.67,37.96)
x3 = c(16.86,17.33,18.77,19.25,20.73,21.23,22.74,23.25,24.78,25.30,26.84,27.36,28.92,29.44,31.01,31.54,33.14,33.68,35.32,35.87,37.54,38.10,39.80,40.37,42.08,42.65,44.37,44.94,46.64,47.20,47.76,48.32)
y3 = c(17.24,17.71,19.09,19.55,20.90,21.34,22.65,23.07,24.33,24.73,25.93,26.31,27.46,27.83,28.93,29.29,30.37,30.72,31.78,32.12,33.16,33.50,34.50,34.83,35.81,36.12,37.05,37.35,38.20,38.48,38.75,39.01)
x4 = c(17.29,17.67,18.84,19.24,20.44,20.85,22.07,22.49,23.73,24.15,25.39,25.81,27.06,27.48,28.73,29.15,30.40,30.83,32.11,32.54,33.87,34.32,35.68,36.15,37.55,38.03,39.45,39.93,41.36,41.84,43.27,43.74,45.18,45.66,47.11,47.59,48.07,48.55)
y4 = c(16.55,16.95,18.17,18.57,19.77,20.16,21.33,21.72,22.85,23.22,24.32,24.68,25.73,26.08,27.10,27.44,28.44,28.77,29.75,30.07,31.02,31.33,32.26,32.56,33.46,33.75,34.61,34.90,35.73,36.00,36.80,37.06,37.84,38.09,38.82,39.06,39.29,39.51)
x5 = c(18.28,18.78,20.27,20.78,22.30,22.81,24.35,24.87,26.42,26.94,28.50,29.01,30.57,31.10,32.67,33.20,34.81,35.36,37.02,37.59,39.31,39.89,41.65,42.25,44.04,44.64,46.43,47.03,47.62,48.22,48.81)
y5 = c(15.78,16.26,17.68,18.14,19.52,19.97,21.30,21.74,23.04,23.47,24.74,25.16,26.39,26.80,28.00,28.40,29.57,29.95,31.10,31.48,32.62,33.00,34.13,34.51,35.61,35.97,37.03,37.37,37.70,38.02,38.34)
x6 = c(18.07,18.61,20.25,20.80,22.48,23.05,24.75,25.32,27.02,27.59,29.30,29.87,31.58,32.16,33.90,34.49,36.30,36.91,38.77,39.41,41.32,41.97,43.92,44.57,46.52,47.17,47.82,48.47)
y6 = c(16.49,17.01,18.54,19.04,20.54,21.03,22.48,22.95,24.36,24.82,26.18,26.62,27.95,28.39,29.69,30.12,31.41,31.84,33.12,33.55,34.81,35.22,36.44,36.83,37.97,38.33,38.69,39.03)
x7 = c(17.41,17.76,18.84,19.20,20.30,20.67,21.79,22.16,23.28,23.66,24.78,25.16,26.29,26.66,27.79,28.17,29.30,29.67,30.81,31.19,32.33,32.72,33.89,34.29,35.50,35.92,37.17,37.60,38.89,39.33,40.64,41.07,42.38,42.82,44.12,44.55,45.84,46.26,47.54,47.96,48.38)
y7 = c(16.73,17.11,18.22,18.59,19.68,20.04,21.10,21.44,22.46,22.79,23.77,24.09,25.03,25.34,26.25,26.55,27.43,27.72,28.57,28.85,29.67,29.94,30.74,31.01,31.80,32.06,32.84,33.10,33.88,34.14,34.91,35.17,35.92,36.17,36.90,37.14,37.83,38.06,38.70,38.91,39.11)

max_ln <- max(c(length(x1), length(x2), length(x3), length(x4), length(x5), length(x6), length(x7))) 

df <- data.frame(col1 = c(x1,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x1))), 
             col2 = c(y1,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y1))), 
             col3 = c(x2,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x2))), 
             col4 = c(y2,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y2))),
             col5 = c(x3,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x3))), 
             col6 = c(y3,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y3))), 
             col7 = c(x4,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x4))), 
             col8 = c(y4,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y4))),
             col9 = c(x5,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x5))), 
             col10 = c(y5,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y5))), 
             col11 = c(x6,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x6))), 
             col12 = c(y6,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y6))),
             col13 = c(x7,rep(NA, max_ln - length(x7))), 
             col14 = c(y7,rep(NA, max_ln - length(y7))))
```

The plot of the data is also shown, and from the figure, we can visually observe three groups.

I am trying to cluster (group) the trajectories with a similar pattern in R. I have seen how to cluster the time series data, but I don't know how to cluster such kind of data. I don't know which package can be used and how to code in R

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how the groups are defined? This does not look like 3 groups to my eye.

Comment: This question might be a better fit at stats.stackexchange.com. If it does end up there though, it would require you to get into a lot more detail on what you're trying to achieve or what underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: maybe: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330751/clustering-spatial-lines-in-r-by-direction

Answer (score -4):

```
# Combine x and y coordinates into a single matrix
data <- cbind(x = c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7), 
              y = c(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7))

# Perform K-means clustering
k <- 3  # Number of clusters
set.seed(123)  # Set seed for reproducibility
kmeans_result <- kmeans(data, centers = k)

# Get cluster assignments
cluster_assignments <- kmeans_result$cluster

# Visualize the clusters
plot(data, col = cluster_assignments, pch = 20, 
     main = "K-means Clustering of Trajectories", 
     xlab = "X Coordinate", ylab = "Y Coordinate")
points(kmeans_result$centers, col = 1:k, pch = 3, cex = 2)
legend("topright", legend = 1:k, col = 1:k, pch = 20, title = "Cluster")
```

Comment: This does not group the trajectories at all. It puts all the points into one large group then does k means clustering on all these points. The OP wants each trajectory intact, but the trajectories to be grouped. This looks a lot like the type of answer one might get from ChatGPT (the formatting, variable naming and missing-the-point are all quite suggestive)

Comment: @AllanCameron, I exactly looking the same what u said. I tried to get the code from ChatGPT, but not getting the expected outcome. can you help me in this regard?

Comment: @Kumar not unless you respond to my earlier comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @AllanCameron, there are trajectories of different samples moving from 'a' to 'b'. I need to cluster these trajectories based on their path taken. From the figure, we can observe that a few trajectories are very close, and a few trajectories are a bit away from that group. In the figure, the x and y axes are representing the position in meters.

Comment: @AllanCameron Clustering these trajectories would be helpful in understanding the behaviour of samples, like why they traveled in that path only. In this data set, the data points for each sample are different. For example, sample A has only 15 XY points and sample B has 25 XY points for traveling from 'a' to 'b' and so on. here, the clustering should be done as unsupervised. Hope, I responded to your earlier comment for clarification.

Comment: @AllanCameron This problem is similar to time series clustering, but in time series the data is one-dimensional, and here, in the trajectories, the data is two-dimensional.

Comment: @Kumar I do understand, but I just don't really see any clustering. Sure, a few of the lines are a bit closer together at one end, but they then overlap and end fairly randomly on the right. What criteria would you use to cluster? Is it the relative positions at the start of the trajectory? The end of the trajectory? If it is the overall trajectory then is it the overall vector between start and end, or the shape of the curve, or the number of points? Without a clear set of rules for what constitutes a cluster, it's difficult to create an algorithm to do it.

Comment: @AllanCameron I would like to use distance metrics like DTW, euclidean, etc., between the points of one to many trajectories, just like how we do for time series clustering.